# How to connect one id from one table to a value from another table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created 3 tables, Requests, RequestTypes and RequestStates with foreign keys. I have a form and i will have a dropdown list with the RequestTypes, for example (Holidays, Low Medical). The user will choose the type of request on a select with options like i said before. I want a foreach on that select displaying the type of requests that i have on my table RequestTypes with an id (foreign key (TypeId) on table Requests).

After submit the form, will create a object with the values that you see on table Requests because i have a http post to put the object on database (Table Requests). In the dropdown list (on the form to submit)i want to appear the string and not the id, so i need to put the information about the table RequestTypes but i want , when the user choose for example the type "Holiday" that the id is 1, fill the object with TypeId = 1. But i want to appear on select options, in form, the string and not the id. Is that possible with a Entity Framework query?? I dont know if is possible to join the 2 tables. I posted the image with the 2 tables that i need. Thanks!

[Tables Entity Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHcjG.png)

Comment: Can you please explain in more details with some code? almost every query and command is possible with entity framework

Comment: Hello! I answered my question with the problem resolved. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. It was simple.

This is the code that i have on my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Requests rqst)
    {

        using (CiberbitHolidayTest context = new CiberbitHolidayTest())
        {
            ViewBag.requestTypes = context.RequestTypes.ToList();

        }

        return View("TimeOff");
    }
```

What I had to do was put on my select option in razor view the value = "Type Id" and the
option = "Name", because the value is about the server. It was simple but i thinked i needed to make a query.

Here is the part of code about the foreach to list the items in the select option.

```
<label for="example-text-input" class="col-8 col-form-label">Absence Type</label>
                        <div class="form-group row">  
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                   <select id="absenceType" name="absenceType" ng-model="NewRequest.TypeId" class="form-control">
                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.requestTypes) { 

                                <option value="@item.TypeId">@item.Name</option>
                                }

                            </select>
                          </div>     
                      </div>
```